# C# Web API call

Tags: c#, json, api

This is the first time i've tried making a call to an API and I'm struggling a little. I keep getting back my error message, I plan on using the json response to populate my object. The OMDB api instructions are here (not helpful though): http://www.omdbapi.com/

```
private static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.omdbapi.com/?");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("t=Captain+Phillips&r=json").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error with feed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4):

You have placed the question mark (`?`) on the wrong place. Try like this:

```
private static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.omdbapi.com");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("?t=Captain+Phillips&r=json");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error with feed");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the question mark is here:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("?t=Captain+Phillips&r=json");
```

and not on the base url as you placed it.

Also in order to properly write your asynchronous method you need to `await` on it inside and not be eagerly calling the `.Result` property which of course is a blocking operation.

Comment: Where does it say that it contacts the QueryString part to the base address. Ive looked [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944(v=vs.118).aspx) but it says URI. but where is the officeal doc that says that it appends the QS to the base ?  ( in GetAsync)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I am not quite sure whether there's official documentation for this. Just look with Fiddler to know what happens under the covers and the exact HTTP request that gets sent.